# distinct set operator in linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I want display data without repetition, so I used a `LINQ to SQL` query with a distinct operator, I override Equals and GeHashCode methods in my model class(ADO.NET entity data model) but its not working for me.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    distinctContext db = new distinctContext();           
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<student> result= (from n in db.students select n).Distinct().ToList();
        return View(result);
    }
}


public partial class student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string studentName { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalMarks { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this.studentName==((student)obj).studentName&& this.TotalMarks==((student)obj).TotalMarks;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.studentName.GetHashCode() ^ this.TotalMarks.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: you want distinct by which column?

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupby extension method on the list with desired column name and select the first result in the group.

```
List<student> result= (from n in db.students select n).ToList();
var distinctStudents=student.GroupBy(s=> s.studentName).Select(grp => grp.First());
```

Check the example [here](https://ideone.com/Ey2bxZ)

Answer (score 0):

When using `Distinct` you have to be avare: if you have a preceeding `Select` with a single column that is a `value-type` then the `Distinct` works without interaction. But, as in your case, when you have a complex object you have to ensure that either

- The class implements `IEquatable<T>`
- You pass an object of type `IEqualityComparer<T>` as parameter

doing the first option you could just use `Distinct`

```
public class Student : IEquatable<Student >
{
    [...]
    public bool Equals(Student other)
    {
        [...]
    }
    public int GetHashCode()
    {
        [...]
    }
}
```

The second option, in case if you do not have access to the class `Student` you have to call

```
Distinct(new StudentEqualityComparer());

public class StudentEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<student>
{
    public bool Equals(Student first, Student second)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(first, second))
            return true;
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(first, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(second, null))
            return false;
        return first.Id == second.Id && first.studentName == second.studentName ;

    }
}
```

Comment: @IvanStoev well, you are right. I have changed that part.

Answer (score 0):

> so I used a **`LINQ to SQL`** query with a distinct operator

That's the problem, LINQ to SQL query distinct operator is processed by the database query (including all the table columns), thus your overrides have no effect.

You have two options:

(1) Force distinct operator to be processed by the LINQ to Objects. You can do that by inserting `AsEnumerable` before the `Distinct` call:

```
var result = db.students.AsEnumerable().Distinct().ToList();
```

(2) Put your distinct logic in the query so it will execute inside the database:

```
var result =
    (from s in db.students  
     group s by new { s.studentName, s.TotalMarks } into g  
     select g.FirstOrDefault()
    ).ToList();
```